Understanding the Quantum Espresso output format for computing the DoS and pDoS
To compute the DOS and PDOS,  there is need to compute the following:
|<psi_alpa|psi_nk>| delta(omega) 

this is summed over the atomic orbitals (alpha) and projected the single particle states psi_nk. Where exactly is this information in the QE outputs including the data-file-xml? i need to reach the psi_alpha, and the psi_nk.
